# Id clash between responses/models in my backbone collection

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, backbone.js

I have a MySQL db containing a files table and a folder table with the foreign keys on the files table relating to the folder table. For the folders collection, I have to populate the collection with folder models and file models. Because the diff models ids clashes one model obliterates the other. My question is, how do I over come this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid id clash in this case you might want to change which attribute Backbone will use as id. Standard is the attribute "id" but you can modify this by changing the idAttribute property.

Here's how you do it:

```
idAttribute: 'uniqueId',
```

Where uniqueId is a attribute you know for sure never will clash.

If you don't have a unique value you must create one. This could be done by overriding the parse function (called when data is received from back end). This is how you create a composite id:

```
parse:function(data){
  if(_.isArray(data){
    _.each(data, function(record){
      record['uniqueId'] = record['id'] + ':' + ([check if record is a file] ? record['folderId'] : '');
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Now all your folders uniqueId will be the same as their id and the files uniqueId will be file id and folder id combined.

Comment: this will mean an extra column in my table?

Comment: Not necessary @Remi Adeoye. You can override the parse function (called when answer is received from back end) and modify the answer to have one unique value per model. For example you could create a composite id. See my edit in the answer above.